# ошибка при запуске docker

Tags: docker

```
sudo docker ps
```

в ответ получаю

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

При проверке - `sudo service docker status`
Выдает результат

```
docker start/pre-start, process 1357
```

Значит сервис запущен

Пробывал `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` - не помагает

**/etc/default/docker** -

```
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
```

Comment: докер запущен, а чего ты хочешь?

Comment: @ArcherGodson sudo docker ps и любая команда не работает, а так то все ок

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил, а есть смысл? думаю никакого

Comment: смысл понять как у вас демон запущен. а есть ли у вас сокет **/var/run/docker.sock**? какие у него атрибуты?

Comment: как вы устанавливали docker?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman права только для рута, ну под рутом тоже пробывал нет не работает

Comment: @MikhailVaysman установил вот так https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/linux_install_help/#prerequisites

Comment: @modelfak посмотрите в списке процессов как именно запущен демон. С какими параметрами?